# If $\mathbf{X}$ is a sigma-algebra on $X$ and $A, B \in \mathbf{X}$, then $A-B \in \mathbf{X}$.

Tags: measure-theory

I know a sigma-algebra must satisfy three conditions: contain the empty set and the whole set, be closed for complements, and be closed for countable unions (and therefore also closed for countable intersections).

I feel as though a starting point would be to state that both the complement of $A$, or $\mathbb{X}-A$, and $B$, or $\mathbb{X}-B$, are in the sigma algebra and then somehow manipulate the union of these complements.  I am not sure how that would eliminate the $\mathbb{X}$ or bring the $B$ in front, but I am at a loss for how to begin this proof.

Comment: Since $B^c$ is measurable, perhaps explore $A \cap B^c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$A-B = \{x \in X; x \in A, x \notin B\} = \{x \in X; x \in A, x \in B^c\} = A \cap B^c$$

Comment: Yup...now I see what to do.  I am also glad I did not ask the second part because I should be able to figure it out myself now.  Thanks.